# Send Request in background

Tags: android, android-studio, notifications, android-notifications, openweathermap

How can I run service in background to send periodic request to server and show notification from server response to user even app is killed(swiped left or right)?

Answer (score 1):

Please let me break your question in few parts and answer them one by one.

1. How can I run service in background - [Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) are usually running in background.
2. Send periodic request - `AlarmManager` is a good choice for repeating behaviour. Please read more about [here](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms)
3. Show notification from server response - please be more specific about what type of notification you have in mind, you need a custom or [show a standard one](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification). Also you can implement [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) and put your logic behind handling notifications.

What research have you done, do you have any code you are struggling?

Comment: Why are you asking a question in your Answer?